# Vuex test with jest throw error even if the function in the store execute well

Tags: firebase, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vuex

what its the deal with this error?[image]

I check all the differents ways to solve it and even in the console the function that I’m testing works fine, pass from false to true with the mutations,

this is the code in the store

the action, this works fine, call to firebase, and log the user correctly.

```
 async login({ commit }, payload) {
  await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password);

  commit("toggleAuth");
  window.location.reload();
},
```

the `login` function executes the commit and then enter the `toggleAuth` mutation

```
  toggleAuth() {
  this.state.userLoggedIn = !this.state.userLoggedIn;
},
```

all of this its  tested like this.

```js
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import auth from "@/store/modules/auth.js";
import { cloneDeep } from "lodash";

jest.mock("@/includes/firebase.js", () => ({
  auth: {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword: () => Promise.resolve(),
  },
}));

describe("Vuex store test", () => {
  test("toggleAuth mutations sets user logged in to true", () => {
    const clonedAuth = cloneDeep(auth);
    const store = createStore({
      modules: { auth: clonedAuth },
    });
    expect(store.state.auth.userLoggedIn).not.toBe(true);
    store.commit("toggleAuth");
    expect(store.state.userLoggedIn).toBe(true);
  });

  test("login action sets usserlogged ", async () => {
    const clonedAuth = cloneDeep(auth);
    const store = createStore({
      modules: { auth: clonedAuth },
    });
    expect(store.state.auth.userLoggedIn).toBe(false);
    await store.dispatch("login", {
      email: "dittler.a@gmail.com",
      password: "123456",
    });
    expect(store.state.auth.userLoggedIn).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A router or `location` shouldn't be used as is in tests because Jest uses fake browser environment. They should be mocked in unit tests as they result in side effects.

The error means that `location.reload` is not implemented in JSDOM, and it couldn't be implemented in a reasonable way because tests doesn't run in browser window.

It should be:

```
jest.spyOn(location, 'reload');
store.commit("toggleAuth");
expect(store.state.userLoggedIn).toBe(true);
expect(location.reload).toBeCalledTimes(1);
```

This should be used together with `jest.restoreAllMocks` and `jest.clearAllMocks` or their configuration counterparts.